# MKAnnotationView / Mokriya Example - dynamic loading images into map

Tags: mkmapview, nsurl, mkannotation, mkannotationview, sdwebimage

i have a problem i need to know how to pass a dynamic URL which i wanna get from the database to display on the map.

I use this code ... from mokriya and the extension SDWebImage which is explained here, with code...

http://blog.mokriya.com/post/15342072745/dynamic-annotations-mkannotationview-for-ios-mapkit

the problem i have is that this is not dynamic because the is always used a

defined IMAGE_URL_STRING

but i need to pass a dynamic generated URL and not a defined one...

somebody any idea how i could realize this with this code of mokriya

The Example of mokriya displays always the same picture ...

or how can i pass a URL to the Funktion

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This might help you in fixing the issue

```
NSMutableArray *infoArray;   // Load ImageURLS you fetch from database here
```

example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
{
    NSString *imageURLString;
    if (i%2==0) {
        imageURLString = @"http://www.mokriya.com/images/tree_people_150px.png";
    } else {
        imageURLString = @"http://www.mokriya.com/images/mokriyalogo_sm.png";
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:imageURLString,@"image_url", nil];
    [infoArray addObject:dict];
    [dict release];
}
```

and inside mapview's delegate method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

use this code

```
   NSMutableDictionary *dict  = [self.infoArray objectAtIndex:anno.tag];
   NSURL *ImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[dict valueForKey:@"image_url"]];
   [pinView setImageWithURL:ImageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
```

We have also pushed changes to 
https://github.com/mokriya/customMKAnnotationView

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i still don't figured it out, i think because i use a ViewController instead of a MKMapView :(

Comment: Take Look at these files  1)https://github.com/mokriya/customMKAnnotationView/blob/master/customMapAnnotation/MapView.h  2)https://github.com/mokriya/customMKAnnotationView/blob/master/customMapAnnotation/MapView.m  ,These files are ViewControllers and have MKMapView *mapview; as property